# Cannot connect to MySQL using MySQLi_connect

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to fetch results using ajax,php and MySql. However I am getting following errors on my server side script.

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource
>   given in D:\htdocs\classes\xxx on line 10
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link
>   resource

The server side code is as follows:

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","abcd123") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 

mysqli_select_db($con,"payrolldb001") or die ("no database"); 

$sql="SELECT substationid,substationcode FROM wms_substation WHERE assemblylineid = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


echo "<select>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "here";
  echo "<option>". $row['substationcode'] . "</option>";
  }
echo "</select>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I can not figure out where am i going wrong.Please help.

Comment: The code you have posted is not the exact one generating the error you mentioned. This code has all mysqli functions and cannot produce a MySQL_ error like this one `Warning: **mysql_query():** supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource`

Comment: the browser wasnt getting the changed code, i deleted the cache and offline content and it worked fine. thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","abcd123","payrolldb001") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
$sql="SELECT substationid,substationcode FROM wms_substation WHERE assemblylineid = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
...
```

**Or**

```
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","abcd123") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 

mysqli_select_db($con,"payrolldb001") or die ("no database");
```

Read [mysqli_select_db](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)

Comment: worked fine, it appears that the browser was not getting the new files and was caching despite the changes made earlier.

Comment: @Dagon OP used before `localhost`

Answer (score 3):

```
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    //Open a new connection to the MySQL server
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','dbu','password','dbname');

    //Output any connection error
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    //MySqli Select Query
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users");

    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["id"];
    }  


    // Frees the memory associated with a result
    $results->free();

    // close connection 
    $mysqli->close();
```